# Poisson Process find P(N(u)=i | N(t)=n)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

given 
$$u<t, i \leq n, $$
find
$$P(N(u)=i | N(t)=n)$$ in terms of $N(t)$

I'm not really sure if it's applicable, but I found a theorem 
that pretty much says that the number of events occurring prior to time u is binomial with parameters n and u/t.

The theorem is below. However, I'm still not sure how to get the answer only in terms of N(t).

Comment: what's $s$ in the title?

Comment: @Alex, typo, just corrected

Comment: The theorem above can be proven using the stationary property of poisson process, its not ${n \choose i}$ rather the permutation. where did you find this theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This theorem gives the answer. It's binomial with parameters $\frac{u}{t}$ and $n$. The formula given in the theorem is correct. Are you looking for a proof of this fact?

When they say "in terms of $N(t)$", they really mean "in terms of $n$". They are conditioning on the event $N(t)=n$, after all. On that event, the two quantities are exactly the same.

(I would've written this as a comment, but MSE won't let me.)